# Compare two multidimensional arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, console-application

I want to write some logic in c# for two multidimensional arrays.
I know that I can use SequenceEqual to verify and return true if they are in the same order
How would I still return true, if the arrays inside the multidimensional array had elements in different locations?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string[,] actual = new string[,]
    {
      {"fruitname", "fruitcolor", "fruitshape"},
      {"banana", "yellow", "rectangle"},
      {"apple", "red", "round"}
    };

    string[,] user1 = new string[,]
    {
      {"fruitname", "fruitcolor", "fruitshape"},
      {"banana", "yellow", "rectangle"},
      {"apple", "red", "round"}
    };
    
    string[,] user2 = new string[,]
    {
      {"fruitshape", "fruitname", "fruitcolor"},
      {"rectangle", "banana", "yellow"},
      {"round", "apple", "red"}
    };
    
    Console.WriteLine(VerifyQueries(actual, user2));
  }

  public static bool VerifyQueries(string[,] storedQuery, string[,] userQuery) {
    // Check length & number of elements in the array
    if(storedQuery.Rank == userQuery.Rank &&
        Enumerable.Range(0,storedQuery.Rank)
        .All(dimension => storedQuery.GetLength(dimension) ==                                   userQuery.GetLength(dimension))
      )
    { 
      // Check if they are exactly the same, return true
      if(storedQuery.Cast<string>().SequenceEqual(userQuery.Cast<string>())) {
        return true;
      }

      //Check if they have matching elements in different index
      for(int i = 0; i < storedQuery.GetLength(0); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < storedQuery.GetLength(1); j++) {
          
        }
      }

    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

currently, I am returning true for actual and user1 arrays.
**I want to return true also for actual and user2**.

Comment: Why is that a multidimensional array at all? I see here an easy to handle `List<Fruit>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could flatten the arrays to 1D array then sort them and compare as you are doing in your code.

```
var storedFlat = storedQuery.Cast<string>().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
var userFlat = userQuery.Cast<string>().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

return storedFlat.SequenceEqual(userFlat);
```

Comment: @SakshamSaraswat Note that this will return true if all the items are the same, but the rows are in a different order. For example, `{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}` compared to `{"g", "h", "i"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "c"}` will return true. Is this what you actually want?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes by the given examples in the question

Comment: Because if that's the case you don't need to sort anything, you can just `return !storedQuery.Cast<string>().Except(userQuery.Cast<string>()).Any();` which will be `O(N)` rather than `O(N.Log(N))` complexity. But I'd like to see what the OP says!

Comment: @MatthewWatson sorting is the simplest solution, as OP has not asked for the performant solution. but for your concern let the OP respond

Comment: Also consider that this will return `true` when comparing `{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}` and `{"i", "a", "d"}, {"e", "g", "b"}, {"c", "h", "f"}` - i.e. it's true even though none of the rows match at all. This might well be what the OP wants, but it's definitely worth confirming.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
public static bool VerifyQueries(string[,] storedQuery, string[,] userQuery)
{
    // Check length & number of elements in the array
    if (storedQuery.Rank != userQuery.Rank ||
        Enumerable.Range(0, storedQuery.Rank).Any(dimension => storedQuery.GetLength(dimension) != userQuery.GetLength(dimension)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if they are exactly the same, return true
    if (storedQuery.Cast<string>().SequenceEqual(userQuery.Cast<string>()))
    {
        return true;
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> row(string[,] array, int r) // Convenience method to return elements of one row.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(1); ++i)
        {
            yield return array[r, i];
        }
    }

    //Check if they have matching elements in different index
    for (int i = 0; i < storedQuery.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if (row(storedQuery, i).Except(row(userQuery, i)).Any())
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Notes:

1. I've changed the dimension check so that it returns `false` at the start of the method, to avoid unnecessary indentation.
2. I've added a local method to enumerate the elements of one row - this simplifies the code somewhat.
3. I'm checking if two rows differ by using `.Except()`. This will return an empty sequence if the two rows are identical ignoring order, or a non-empty sequence if the two rows contain different elements. Then I can use `.Any()` to determine if we need to return `false` (because a non-empty result means that the rows contain different elements).
4. This uses `.Except()` rather than sorting, meaning it has `O(N)` complexity rather than `O(N.Log(N))`

Comment: Could you explain why you need the "Check if they are exactly the same"? Because in the worst case it will go through the arrays twice. I think it makes sense just in case when we have additional bool argument strictOrder.

Comment: @YevhenCherkes That's the original code from the OP. I agree it's not really necessary, but I assumed that the OP had it there as an optimisation. It's an O(N) comparison so if the lists are normally the same, it could be more performant than always using the `O(N.Log(N))` complexity `Except()` operation.